# Partial fractions of complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I've just reviewed this answer: [partial fraction for complex roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546961/partial-fraction-for-complex-roots)

Whilst I understand most of it, there is one component I am having some trouble understanding. in particular

$$\frac {2s^2+5s+12} {(s^2+2s+10)(s+2)}=\frac a{s+2}+\frac {b+cs}{s^2+2s+10}$$

Can someone take me through where the cs term comes from? I assume it something related to simplifying

$$\frac {A} {s+1+3i} + \frac {B}{s+1-3i}$$

but I cannot seem to get to the bottom of it. I end up with

$$\frac {A(s+1-3i)+B(s+1+3i)} {s^2+2+10}$$

and unsure where to go from here to get something that looks like the term

$$\frac {b+cs}{s^2+2s+10}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In numerator, you factor by s. you will get two terms.

Answer (score 1):

The $cs$ terms is present in real [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).  You are decomposing into proper rational functions, but when the denominator has degree $2$, your numerator must have degree $1$ to represent all possible proper rational functions.  The correct form for a general factor $a x^n + \cdots + b$ of the denominator is 
$$  \frac{A x^{n-1} + B x^{n-2} + \cdots  + C x + D}{a x^n + \cdots + b}  \text{,}  $$
that is, the numerator is always one degree less then the factor in the denominator.  (If the factor appears to a power, the numerator still gets its degree from the factor; it ignores the power.)

This is demonstrated on the partial fractions page as [example 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Example_2).

More pointedly, say one needs to decompose
$$  \frac{x^2}{x(x^2-4x+8)}  $$
There is no solution in reals $A$ and $B$ such that 
$$  \frac{x^2}{x(x^2-4x+8)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2-4x+8}  \text{.}  $$
When you clear the denominators, to match the quadratic coefficients, $A = 1$, but there is no choice of $B$ such that $-4x+8+Bx = 0$.  For a solution to exist, you need 
$$  \frac{x^2}{x(x^2-4x+8)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{Bx + C}{x^2-4x+8}  $$
to arrive at $-4x+8+Bx + C = 0$, which does have a solution.

Now, as to your particular problem ...  Clearing denominators, we have  \begin{align*}
2s^2+5s+12 &= \frac{a (s^2+2s+10)(s+2)}{s+2}+\frac {(b+cs)(s^2+2s+10)(s+2)}{s^2+2s+10}  \\
    &= a (s^2+2s+10) + (b+cs)(s+2)  \\
    &= (as^2 + 2as + 10a) + (b(s+2)+cs(s+2))  \\
    &= (as^2 + 2as + 10a) + (bs+2b+cs^2 + 2cs)  \\
    &= (a+c) s^2 + (2a + b + 2c)s + (10a + 2b)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
For two polynomials (real or complex) to agree, they must agree in each coefficient, so we have the system
\begin{align*}
a + c &= 2  \\
2a+b+2c &= 5  \\
10a+2b &= 12
\end{align*}
Subtracting two copies of the second from the first, $b = 1$.  Using that in the third, $a = 1$.  Using that in the first, $c = 1$.  Therefore,
$$  \frac {2s^2+5s+12}{(s+2)(s^2+2s+10)} = \frac{1}{s+2} + \frac{s+1}{s^2+2s+10}  \text{.}  $$

That's the real decomposition.  Continuing, using the complex factoring
$$  s^2+2s+10 = (s - (-1-3\mathrm{i}))(s - (-1+3\mathrm{i}))  \text{,}  $$
$$  \frac{s+1}{s^2+2s+10} = \frac{d}{s - (-1-3\mathrm{i}))} + \frac{e}{s - (-1+3\mathrm{i}))}  \text{.}  $$
Clearing denominators, we obtain
\begin{align*}
s+1 &= \frac{d(s^2+2s+10)}{s - (-1-3\mathrm{i}))} + \frac{e(s^2+2s+10)}{s - (-1+3\mathrm{i}))}  \\
    &= d(s - (-1+3\mathrm{i})) + e(s - (-1-3\mathrm{i}))  \\
    &= ds - d(-1+3\mathrm{i})) + es - e(-1-3\mathrm{i}))  \\
    &= (d+e)s +d -3d\mathrm{i} + es + e +3e\mathrm{i}  \\
\end{align*}
Again equating coefficients, \begin{align*}
    d+e &= 1  \\
    d+e + 3(-d+e)\mathrm{i} &= 1 + 0 \mathrm{i}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Subtracting the first of these from the second, $3(-d+e)\mathrm{i} = 0$, forcing $d = e$.  Then the first gives $d = e = 1/2$.

The development above first expanded in factors of the denominator that were reducible over the reals, then factored further over the complexes.  These can be done all at once.

$$  \frac{2s^2+5s+12}{(s^2+2s+10)(s+2)} = \frac{a }{s+2}+\frac{d}{s - (-1-3\mathrm{i}))} + \frac{e}{s - (-1+3\mathrm{i}))}  \text{.}  $$
Now all the denominators are (powers of) factors of degree $1$, so their numerators have degree $0$.

Comment: oof this is more complicated than I bargained for. Okay thanks for the answer, I think I understand, not sure if this is the kind of answer my prof is expecting from me though